# Magic packet (Wake up on LAN) not send from Realtek RTL8111E (windows)

Tags: windows, wake-on-lan, realtek

Trying to send magic packet from NIC Realtek RTL8111E on Motherboard MSi B75MA-P45 (using wol.exe) and nothing. Server does not wake up but magic packet from other PC, with other NIC (using wol.exe) successfully wakes up the server.

How to wake up the server from Realtek RTL8111E using magic packet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using another tool to send those magic packets (WOL) in my living room pc which is called **[Wake On Lan GUI](http://www.depicus.com/wake-on-lan/wake-on-lan-gui.aspx)** from [Depicus](http://www.depicus.com/). 
Try this one to see if its working... The same company released also a [monitor utility](http://www.depicus.com/wake-on-lan/wake-on-lan-monitor.aspx) which you can monitor those packets on a subnet and check if the signal is reaching that subnet.

[image]

Comment: Alex, your program can wake up on Realtek RTL8111E only when "Send options" specified as Internet and provided all options (MAC, IP, Subnet mask). On other PC wake up when option "Send Options" specifed as Local subnet and MAC address only. What the difference between Realtek RTL8111E  and Intel (and 3Com)? ALL PC connect same type, network switch (2 cascade) is unmanaged.